# Datagridview checkbox column only allowing me to select one check box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Ok, the first column in my datagridview is a checkbox.  I have 'multiselect' set to true and that does indeed work.  However, a user is only allowed to check one checkbox at a time, if they select another the original unchecks itself, how do I stop that?  I need a user to be able to select, say 3 out of 5 rows using the checkbox so that they can carry out a group action.

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataGridView` will by default allow multiple checkboxes to be checked at the same time. Just to make sure I just created a DGV and added one checkbox column and 2 textbox columns to it and I could check multiple rows.

I think you might accidently have done something that makes this happen? Maybe try removing the DGV and creating a new one (or if that's a lot of work, create a new one next to it and then compare the settings for both of them and do a search for the old one to make sure it's not changed dynamically somewhere).

Comment: Thank you, yes I appear to have 'checked' something, what I couldn't find so I rebuilt the whole thing and it works as expected now.  You wouldn't know how I can change the 'selected' color would you?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fixed that other problem as well.  Now if I can just get the gridlines to display and the vertical scroll bar to be there all the time i'm done...  Never enough hours.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the VirtualMode setting to false on the datagridview to check more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally i write

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
DataGridView.Columns.Add(chk);
chk.HeaderText = Check Data;
chk.Name="chk";
```

----->   "chk.FalseValue = true;"    this was causing me the error

after removing it problem resolved

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30027163)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).